# What is the $46^{th}$ term in the sequence $27,-20,13,-6,-1,8,-15$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am doing some practice algebra from [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/curriculum-mathematics-problem/algebra-and-trigonometry-problem-6022/) and I am having some trouble with the following question:

> > What is the $46^{th}$ term in the sequence $27,-20,13,-6,-1,8,-15$

I tried finding the common difference and I also tried to ignoring the minus sign and came up with the following pattern of the differences or sums:

$$-7,-7,-7,5,7,7,7$$

but that didn't help. If someone could provide some hints, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Can you find a closed form for the sequence as a function of $n$?

Comment: @Amzoti Sorry, I don't know what "closed form" means. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Some observations. We see that the sign is alternating (how can we represent that)? Ignoring this sign, we see that the difference is $7$ between terms. Can you find a starting point using all of the facts? It will look like $a_n =$ <sign changing> ( Common Term + constant), where the constant is a starting point. Trying not to give the entire answer away. Hope it is clear

Comment: Technically you can't really prove the sequence adheres to any pattern at all, I could define any number of sequences that have those same first terms but then define the 46th term to be what ever I want, the question over all is pretty vague imo.

Comment: @Ethan: That's a cop-out. Should we just tear out the sections on sequences and series from all the low-level text books? I've got a handful of PreCalculus (Larson, et al) books that I'd prefer not to desecrate.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Split the sequence into two:
$$a_{2n+1}=27-14n$$
$$a_{2n}=-20+14n$$

Answer (score 1):

$27+-20=7\\-20+13=-7\\13+-6=7\\-6+-1=-7\\-1+8=7\\\vdots$

$a_n+a_{n-1}=(-1)^n\times7$

$${ a }_{ 1 }+{ a }_{ 2 }=7\\ -{ a }_{ 2 }-{ a }_{ 3 }=7\\ { a }_{ 3 }+{ a }_{ 4 }=7\\ \vdots \\ -{ a }_{ 44 }-{ a }_{ 45 }=7\\ ---------\\ { a }_{ 1 }-{ a }_{ 45 }=7\times 44\\ { a }_{ 45 }=27-7\times 44=-281\\ ---------\\ { a }_{ 45 }+{ a }_{ 46 }=7\\ { a }_{ 46 }=288$$

If my calculations are correct the answer is $288$

Comment: I'm afraid, the answer isn't $-5876$. It's an answer between $0$ and $999$.

Comment: yes you are right. I will edit. I had a calculation error, I know.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell.

For example, there are infinitely many sequences which start $2,4,\ldots$

For any $k \in \mathbb{C}$, the sequence $s_n :=kn^2+(2-3k)n+2k$ starts $s_1=2$ and $s_2=4$.

Moreover, you may choose $k$ to make $s_p$, with $p \ge 3$, to be anything you like.

The same is true for your sequence. There are an uncountably infinitely number of sequence of degree seven in $n$ for which their first seven terms are the same as the ones you have given.

Comment: In general it is impossible, but there's definitely a pattern here.

Comment: I have downvoted. But before Marvis accuses me of being a coward, let me give my apology:

Comment: This answer is (technically) correct, and is a good introductory exposition on something that I sincerely hope *every student of sequences will understand.* That said, a good instructor would a) have explained the presence of many solutions, and b) phrase the question as "find the **apparent** 54th term".

Comment: And sure, those who are too smart for their own good can concoct some sort of ugly "apparent" solution involving splitting fields and the Second Law of Thermodynamics, but the heart - and context - of the question is to just use elementary methods and pattern skills.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers given so far satisfy the recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+2}+2 a_{n+1} + a_n = 0$$

Since the associated equation $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 1 = (\lambda+1)^2$ has a double root at $-1$, the recurrence relation has general solution of the form

$$a_n = (-1)^n (\alpha n + \beta)$$

Substituting the initial condition $a_1 = 27, a_2 = -20$ into above formula give us $\alpha = 7, \beta = -34$. The corresponding formula $\displaystyle a_n = (-1)^{n-1}(34-7n)$ does reproduce the initial sequences. The $46^{th}$ term will be $(-1)^{46-1}(34-7\cdot46) = 288$.

Comment: The answer is $310$ and not $288$. The answer key has split up the numbers, it seems.

Comment: @gekkostate it is 288, not 310. $a_2 = -20, a_4 = -6 \implies a_{2n} = -20 + 14(n\color{red}{-1}) \implies a_{46} = -20+14(23-1) = 288$.

Comment: @gekkostate, answer confirmed on brilliant.org's web site. BTW, the question I saw there is asking for the $56^{th}$  instead of the $46^{th}$ term.

Comment: @achillehui I think each problem has a different term number but I maybe wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The total delta between each term changes by 14 each time.

- $|-20-27| = 47$
- $|13-(-20)| = 33$
- $|-6-13| = 19$
- $|-1-(-6)| = 5$
- Now when we subtract 14 from 5, we get -9, but we're just looking at the magnitude for now...
- $|8-(-1)| = 9$
- $|-15-8| = 23$

Now, appropriately add $\pm$ signs.